# Validation Message in MVC for extracting the unique values by validating from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am new to MVC. I want to add a Validation Message for a input textbox in a cshtml file. The input should have the building names. It should only take the unique names after validating from the database. How should I write the validation message for this input box. Please help.
The code is below:

```
<tr>
   <td style="height: 0.3em;width: 22em;">
     <div style="margin-top: -0.0em;margin-left: 0.8em;">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.buildingName, new { @class = "InfoTextBox", @placeholder = "Building name", id = "buildingName", maxlength = 25, onkeyup = "FormDirty();" })
          <br />                                
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingName)
          <span style="position: absolute; top: 6.6em; left: 14.8em; color: #FF0000; font-size: 1.7em;">*</span>
     </div>
   </td>
```

I have to enhance the validation by only letting it take the unique values. Please help

Comment: You can use a `[Remote]` attribute - [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataAnotation Remote attribute for this like below:

**ViewModel :**

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("buildingName")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckBuildingName", "ControllerName", AdditionalFields = "buildingName", HttpMethod = "Post")]
    public string buildingName { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult CheckBuildingName() {
    string _buildingName = Request.Form["buildingName"]; // put your control name here
    if (repository.isExist(_buildingName)) {
        return Json("Building already taken, Pleaes try with different name.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } else {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Your `.cshtml` code seems fine.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: So I need not do any changes in the .cshtml file right ? What do you mean by repository.isExist ? In that line can i directly access database by using the following code :

Comment: using (var context2 = new Notifier.AccountDatabase(connectionstring))
            {
                var objBuilding = (from building in context2.Buildings
                                   where building.buildingName == model.buildingName && building.buildingActive == true
                                   select building).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: IsExist means you have to check the value from your database table that the record is exist or not

Comment: repository means the class name and isexist is method name

Comment: Yeah so instead of that line I can put the above code and check for validations right?

Comment: yes you can make your own class and own method for checking this

Comment: And in which controller should I include the CheckBuildingName function. Should I create a new controller. Please reply

Comment: Its totally your choice you can use existing controller or you can create new.

Comment: please mark and upvote my solution if it helps you. Thanks :)

Comment: When i use this  [DisplayName("buildingName")] Iam getting the error:  The type or namespace 'Displayname' could not be found.

Comment: Hi @Sunil Kumar : I implemented the code in the way you told. But I get the following exception : "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The controller for path '/ConfigLocationController/CheckBuildingName' was not found or does not implement IController."

Comment: try after removing additional field option from model

Comment: Even after I remove Additional field I get the same exception. I included that function in the already existing controller called ConfigLocationcontroller

Comment: do one thing refer this link :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/

Comment: you can also try this link :http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669824/Implementing-Remote-Validation-in-MVC

Comment: Should I include any dll ? I think that is a dll issue.

Comment: do you seen any error when you are building your code ? OR you are facing this error at run time ?

Comment: Facing this error during run time.. Please help.  Build is successful